# PHP - Pass data from search result into another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Here are three tables that I need to sync together.

-Table 1 is People (name, email etc)

-Table 2 is Cars (brand, color etc)

-Table 3 is Ads (One ad containing info from Table 1 and Table 2)

What I basically want is for "TABLE 1" to be able to search for data from "TABLE 2". When the data is selected I want data from both TABLE 1 and TABLE 2 to be entered into TABLE 3.

When a user is logged in he should be able to search for a products in a search field and choose one product - THIS IS DONE AND WORKS.

The problem is that I don't know how to take the search result, in this example it would be a car. And via a submit button create an AD and enter data in TABLE 3 with the name and email from TABLE 1 and the car model and color from TABLE 2.

**Here is the CODE for the FORM:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>PHP Live MySQL Database Search</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        font-family: Arail, sans-serif;
    }
    /* Formatting search box */
    .search-box{
        width: 300px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .search-box input[type="text"]{
        height: 32px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .result{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    .search-box input[type="text"], .result{
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* Formatting result items */
    .result p{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-top: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .result p:hover{
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get("adsToDb.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });

    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<br>
<br>
<p>Search the product you want to sell</p>
<body>
    <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search product..." />
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<form action="createAd.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>

<input type="submit" name="fields" value="sell this product" />
<input type="hidden" name="fieldsCount" value="<?php echo $fields+1 ?>" />
</form>

</html>
```

**HERE IS THE CODE FOR THE DB SEARCH**

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB", "", "");
    // Set the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
}

// Attempt search query execution
try{
    if(isset($_REQUEST['term'])){
        // create prepared statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE :term";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $term = $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';
        // bind parameters to statement
        $stmt->bindParam(':term', $term);
        // execute the prepared statement
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                echo "<p>" . $row['product_name'] . "</p>";
            }
        } else{
            echo "<p>No matches found";
        }
    }
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
}

// Close connection
unset($pdo);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden field which holds the id of the car inside the forloop of the search result and once user click on button to add to Ad table, already you have the loggedIn User ID and can get from the hidden field the car_id

```
<form action="createAd.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="fields" value="sell this product" />
<input type="hidden" name="fieldsCount" value="<?php echo $fields+1 ?>" />
**<input type="hidden" name="car_id" value="<?php echo $car_id ?>" />**
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Right now the form is separated from the search (you can see the form right at the bottom). How can I connect them? Also, should the form action go to the adsToDb.php or to a new .php file as this example has with createAd.php?

Comment: Yeah, the form should go adsToDb.php file which handles the post request of create new Ad

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob at this, maybe this is a stupid question. But the adsToDb.php already has a DB connection for the searchbar, that is retrieving product information about the cars. Do you suggest that I do one more DB connection in the same file but for the newAD table? Should this not be in a completely new .php file?

Comment: Nah it's ok :) for code organization, It should be in a seperate file and call that file :)